# Why do I need a view class to resolve JSTL views in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am going through Craig Walls [Manning Spring4 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition).

In Creating JSP views, he suggests,

> The InternalResourceViewResolver ultimately resolves logical view
>   names into instances of InternalResourceView that reference JSP files.
>   But if those JSP files are referencing JSTL tags for formatiing or
>   messages, then you may want to configure InternalResourceViewResolver    to resolve a JSTLView instead.

All that's needed to have InternalResourceView Resolver resolver JstlView instead of InternalResourceView is to set its viewClass property.

like this,

```
 @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
            new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }
```

Why do I need to add this line

`resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);`

and what exactly is this class meant for?

Any suggestions?`

Comment: You don't... Spring detects the existince of JSTL automatically and when available will automatically return a `JstlView`. So you are adding nothing here. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.java#L62)

Comment: @Deinum: Agreed, but why does the author of such a nice book mentions that.

Comment: In earlier versions it didn't do that, I guess that it is due to reuse of older material...

Comment: Tried to get the history of `InternalResourceViewResolver` but I guess that wasn't migrated to github from SVN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In older Spring versions there wasn't automatic detection of features. This has been introduced slowly in different classes. The `InternalResourceViewResolver` didn't have automatic detection of JSTL in the early days, this required one to always specify the `JstlView` as the `viewClass`.

However [this revision](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/trunk/src/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.java?p=14417) in the very old SVN that once contained Spring has added it and since then there was automatic detection of which `viewClass` to use.

**Commit Message**

> ---
>
> r14417 | jhoeller | 2007-08-05 00:01:19 +0200 (zo, 05 aug 2007) | 2 lines
>
> InternalResourceViewResolver uses JstlView as default (instead of InternalResourceView) if the JSTL API is present
>
> ---

The reason that it still is in the book I cannot tell, I suspect due to reuse of material from previous releases this has been left in, but that is a guess. Only [the author](https://spring.io/team/cwalls) can answer that question.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out the old SVN uris :) and a bit of digging in the SVN logs. A nice piece of software archeology :).